# From a given pcap file how to filter mac frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wireshark, scapy, pyshark

From a given `pcap` file how do I filter mac frames and display the result in the terminal window?

So far, I have the following code that iterates through all frames

```
import pyshark
cap = pyshark.FileCapture('filename.pcap')
for pkt in cap:
    print pkt
```

I would like to filter out the mac frames.

Comment: The question is : what do you mean by mac frames ? An IP packet that would come from a device with MacOS operating system ?

Comment: @sandwood Maybe [Ethernet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame)? "MAC" can mean "Medium Access Control". This is all part of layer 2 in the OSI model.

Comment: I hope he doesn't mean ethernet.. if he does, that would be pretty much everything. :)